# Is it possible to exclude duration time for embedded resources in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Let us say I have a request that refer to lots of embedded resources.
If I run such request, with `Retrieve all embedded resources from HTML file` enabled, I will get the response time for the whole request duration. This value is pretty much similar to the duration in the browser (depending on `connection pool` size settings).
I'm wondering if there is a possibility to exclude the duration for all embedded resources, but still download those resources.

For example:

**mainRequest** - 13sec

- **subRequest1**(html) - 3sec
- **subRequest2**(css) - 0.5sec
- **subRequest**(jpeg) - 1sec

...

What I need is to exclude timings for the css, images, js etc., and get 3sec as the response time for the mainSample.

I was able to do this with the beanshell, where I reset end time for the **mainSample** by subtracting timings for the desired **subSamples**. However it works only for the `connection pool` size set to 1. If the pool size is larger that this approach is wrong.

Is there are some way to get the same result for the larger `connection pool` size?

Answer (score 0):

When connection pool size is greater than 1, download is made in parallel, so you would need to get the biggest time of subsample and this would potentially give you the time your page took to load (at least on network size), but in my opinion it is meaningless